# How to convert Doc files to docx or pdf format using PHPWord?

Tags: doc, phpword

I am trying to convert Doc(resumes)  files to docx or pdf format using PHPWord.I downloaded PHPWord from github.

I tried Below code

```
require_once '../PHPWord.php';

$PHPWord = new PHPWord();

$document = $PHPWord->loadTemplate('Excel2003.doc');

// Save File

$objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPWord, 'Word2007');

$objWriter->save('Excel2007.docx');
```

But getting error

```
Warning: include(/var/www/html/PHPWord-develop/src/PhpWord/PHPWord.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/PHPWord-develop/readdoc.php on line 8

Warning: include(): Failed opening '/var/www/html/PHPWord-develop/src/PhpWord/PHPWord.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/html/PHPWord-develop/readdoc.php on line 8

Fatal error: Class 'PhpOffice\PHPWord' not found in /var/www/html/PHPWord-develop/readdoc.php on line 9
```

What is the solution?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

After requiring the package and you are sure the current file can read the PhpOffice/PhpWord package then try and replace your code with this:

```
$PHPWord = new \PHPWord();

$document = $PHPWord->loadTemplate('Excel2003.doc');

// Save File

$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($PHPWord, 'Word2007');

$objWriter->save('Excel2007.docx');
```

Then also note that if the doc you are trying to convert is of Word2007, then you can leave the second argument empty.

Comment: Hello, look like the loadTemplate() won't working with ````*.doc```` file, it return error            ````ZipArchive::getFromName(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object````

Comment: I'm fairly certain PHPWord does not support .doc that is why you are getting this error.